# How use jxdatepicker in groovy with swingbuilder?

Tags: java, swing, groovy

Im trying with this code for create a datepicker using swingx and groovy

but i dont know because dont work

Im trying to show the date picker in firs label but not appears nothing

I dont know what is wrong

please help me with program

this is my final code  IM using swingx and javax

and use swingbuilder  please check this code

and help me

**this is not same question Im trying to use wingx jxdatepicker and my code not works
please check this part**

picker.setFormats(new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy"));        tableLayout {
   picker.show()

```
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder 
import groovy.beans.Bindable 
 import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE 
@Grapes(
    @Grab(group='org.swinglabs', module='swingx', version='1.6')
)

import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXDatePicker;
import java.awt.*

@Bindable
class Address { 
    String street, number, city
    String toString() { "address[street=$street,number=$number,city=$city]" }
}

def address = new Address(street: 'Evergreen Terrace', number: '742', city: 'Springfield')

def swingBuilder = new SwingBuilder()
swingBuilder.edt {  // edt method makes sure UI is build on Event Dispatch Thread.
    lookAndFeel 'nimbus'  // Simple change in look and feel.
    frame(title: 'Address', size: [350, 230],
            show: true, locationRelativeTo: null,
            defaultCloseOperation: EXIT_ON_CLOSE) {
        borderLayout(vgap: 5)

        panel(constraints: BorderLayout.CENTER,

                border: compoundBorder([emptyBorder(10), titledBorder('Enter your address:')])) {
        JXDatePicker picker = new JXDatePicker();
        picker.setDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        picker.setFormats(new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy"));

            tableLayout {
       picker.show()
                tr {
                    td {
                             picker
                    }
                    td {
                        textField address.street, id: 'streetField', columns: 20
                    }
                }
                tr {
                    td {
                        label 'Number:'
                    }
                    td {
                        textField id: 'numberField', columns: 5, text: address.number
                    }
                }
                tr {
                    td {
                        label 'City:'
                    }
                    td {
                        textField id: 'cityField', columns: 20, address.city
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        panel(constraints: BorderLayout.SOUTH) {
            button text: 'Save', actionPerformed: {
                println address
            }
        }

        // Binding of textfield's to address object.
        bean address,
            street: bind { streetField.text },
            number: bind { numberField.text },
            city: bind { cityField.text }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example should works if you register `JXDatePicker` correctly the missing line may looks like this:
    registerBeanFactory("datePicker", JXDatePicker)
And you don't need to instantiate JXDatePicker widget neither you need to show it explicitly, SwingBuilder should take care of that, this example works for me:

```
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder 
import groovy.beans.Bindable 
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Calendar
import javax.swing.JFrame
import javax.swing.JPanel
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE 
@Grapes(
    @Grab(group='org.swinglabs', module='swingx', version='1.6')
)

import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXDatePicker
import java.awt.*

@Bindable
class Address { 
    String street, number, city
    String toString() { "address[street=$street,number=$number,city=$city]" }
}

def address = new Address(street: 'Evergreen Terrace', number: '742', city: 'Springfield')

def swingBuilder = new SwingBuilder()
swingBuilder.edt {  // edt method makes sure UI is build on Event Dispatch Thread.
    registerBeanFactory("datePicker", JXDatePicker)
    lookAndFeel 'nimbus'  // Simple change in look and feel.
    frame(title: 'Address', size: [350, 230],
            show: true, locationRelativeTo: null,
            defaultCloseOperation: EXIT_ON_CLOSE) {
        borderLayout(vgap: 5)

        panel(constraints: BorderLayout.CENTER,

                border: compoundBorder([emptyBorder(10), titledBorder('Enter your address:')])) {

            tableLayout {
                tr {                
                    td {
                        label 'Birth Date:'
                    }
                    td {
                        datePicker(date: new Date(), formats: new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy"))
                    }
                }
                tr {                
                    td {
                        label 'Street:'
                    }
                    td {
                        textField address.street, id: 'streetField', columns: 20
                    }
                }

                tr {
                    td {
                        label 'Number:'
                    }
                    td {
                        textField id: 'numberField', columns: 5, text: address.number
                    }
                }
                tr {
                    td {
                        label 'City:'
                    }
                    td {
                        textField id: 'cityField', columns: 20, address.city
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        panel(constraints: BorderLayout.SOUTH) {
            button text: 'Save', actionPerformed: {
                println address
            }
        }

        // Binding of textfield's to address object.
        bean address,
            street: bind { streetField.text },
            number: bind { numberField.text },
            city: bind { cityField.text }
    } 
}
```

Then you should be able to bind the value of the date picker to the bean Address as well, for more detail check out: [Building Rich Applications with Groovy's SwingBuilder, TS-5098, JavaOne 2008](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/ts-5098-1-159011.pdf)

Hope this helps.